# ajax url does not call php file

Tags: php, ajax

hi simply i want to call my My delete.php file using Ajax url, but i doesn't call the php page. i Redirted to success function without reaching php page.check my code.

==> View.php

```
   $(document).on("click", "#delBtn", function(){ 
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'delete.php',
        data:id,
        success: function () {
          alert("Deleted Successfully");
        },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(error);
          }
    });
 });
```

==> delete.php

```
        <?php

        include_once('database/db.php');
          if(isset($_POST['id'])){

          $id = $_POST['id'];
          var_dump($id);
           exit();
        $getUsers = $connect->prepare("DELETE FROM registration WHERE id = 
         '".$id."' ");
          $getUsers->execute();

       }
       ?>
```

Comment: have you looked in the browser debug panel (f12) under network to make sure it's not a 404, you may want to use the full URL or absolute URL instead of just the filename.

Comment: "but i doesn't call the php page"  How do you know this?  What debugging have you done?  What _does_ happen?

Comment: You also have an SQL injection issue in your query. `WHERE id = 
         '".$id."' "`  For example I could put `$id= '" OR 1 --'` and delete everything in that table.

Comment: `isset($_POST['id'])`  That is never going to be true with your current ajax code

Comment: @PatrickQ - good catch.  I would suggest changing that to `data:{id:id}` and add `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @PatrickQ i put var_dump and exit() function on delete.php file

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  i uisng data:{id:id} but getting same error

Comment: @AamirMansuri - your not setting a key for it.  it's just the value of the ID atm.  You also probably have to tell it the data is JSON.  `dataType: "json"`  and If I remember right `dataType` is case sensitive.

Comment: @AamirMansuri _What_ error?  Your question doesn't mention any error.  And _where_ did you put the `var_dump()`?  What was the output?  You're making it really hard for us to help you.

Comment: @PatrickQ check screen shot https://imgur.com/a/No8lCj9

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `dataType` is for the expected _response_ data.  That wouldn't help OP here.

Comment: Hay I didn't even realize that, I just always use `$.post` ... lol.  I only use Ajax for file upload.  LOL

Comment: reponse of ajax???

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Also, when you give an object to `$.ajax`, it sends it URL-encoded, not JSON. And it's the same for `$.post`.

Comment: @walternuñez without calling php page ajax reaching on success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use key/pair then send data to php file. and At Php file using $_POST['key'] u can retrieve value.